# How to use multiple Filters while executing K2 Smart Object from API?

Tags: k2

I am trying to execute a Get List method of custom K2 Smart Object which queries SQL database object (view). I am using API in my existing C# project to execute these smart objects. I would like to pass multiple filters to this GetList method.

I am using below code to add single filter, but couldn't figure out way to pass multiple filters:

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] results = null;
if (!server.Connection.IsConnected) return results;

SmartObject smartObject = server.GetSmartObject(objectName);
SmartListMethod newList = smartObject.ListMethods["GetList"];
smartObject.MethodToExecute = methodName;

Contains myFilter = new Contains();
myFilter.Left = new PropertyExpression(filterPropertyName, PropertyType.Text);
myFilter.Right = new ValueExpression(filterValue, PropertyType.Text);

newList.Filter = myFilter;

SmartObjectList list = server.ExecuteList(smartObject);

results = new Dictionary<string, string>[list.SmartObjectsList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < list.SmartObjectsList.Count; i++)
{
    results[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    SmartObject smo = list.SmartObjectsList[i];
    foreach (SmartProperty property in smo.Properties)
    {
         results[i].Add(property.Name, property.Value);
    }
}
return results;
```

Like `myFilter` in above code, I would like to pass multiple such filters.

Comment: Found the solution, need to use AND/ OR logical filters to combine other filters like contains and equals.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment with code how to do this for others (and myself after a couple nights sleep and I forget again).  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] results = null;
if (!server.Connection.IsConnected) return results;

SmartObject smartObject = server.GetSmartObject(objectName);
SmartListMethod newList = smartObject.ListMethods["GetList"];
smartObject.MethodToExecute = methodName;

Contains myFilter = new Contains();
myFilter.Left = new PropertyExpression(filterPropertyName, PropertyType.Text);
myFilter.Right = new ValueExpression(filterValue, PropertyType.Text);

    Contains myFilter2 = new Contains();
    myFilter2.Left = new PropertyExpression(filterPropertyName2, PropertyType.Text);
    myFilter2.Right = new ValueExpression(filterValue2, PropertyType.Text);

    Not myFilter3 = new Not(myFilter2);

    // And can have the left and right filters set to pre-defined filteres to combined them!
    And myCombinedFilter = new And();
    myCombinedFilter.Left = myFilter;
    myCombinedFilter.Right = myFilter2;

    // Or also works!
    Or myCombinedFilterOr = new Or();
    myCombinedFilterOr.Left = myCombinedFilter;
    myCombinedFilterOr.Right = myFilter3;

// ((MyFilter && myFilter2) || Not MyFilter2)
newList.Filter = myCombinedFilterOr;

SmartObjectList list = server.ExecuteList(smartObject);

results = new Dictionary<string, string>[list.SmartObjectsList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < list.SmartObjectsList.Count; i++)
{
    results[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    SmartObject smo = list.SmartObjectsList[i];
    foreach (SmartProperty property in smo.Properties)
    {
         results[i].Add(property.Name, property.Value);
    }
}
return results;
```